# Good Percentage Return on Equity?

Tags: investing, ratio

Considering a public retail company existing for more than 47 years, would you suggest 23.12% to be a good percentage return on equity? I know that it is currently better than what banks can offer, but why would you *personally* suggest it?

Here's the numbers:
`avg. equity = 0.5(2 416 000 000+2 404 100 000)
             = 2 410 060 000`
**% Return on Equity**
`(profit after tax/avg. equity)x100/1
= (557 100 000)/(2 410 050 000)×100/1
= 23.12%`

Comment: How does "better than what banks can offer" fit into the calculation of a company's finances?

Comment: I'm working here on an investor's perspectives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes definitely**

Warren Buffet averaged returns of only around [21%](http://www.coattailinvestor.com/) throughout his 40 years in business.

ROE of 23% is probably more than double the ROE of most companies , whats more as the saying goes its easier to grow sales from 1 million to 100 million than to grow sales from 100 million to 10 billion